# Python matplotlib insert index in plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, page-numbering

So I am trying to save multiple plots which are generated after every iteration of a for loop and I want to insert a name tag on those plots like a header with the number of iterations done. code looks like this. I tried suptitle but it does not work.

```
for i in range(steps):

        nor_m = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = 1)
        plt.hexbin(xxx,yyy,C, gridsize=13, cmap=matplotlib.cm.rainbow, norm=nor_m, edgecolors= 'k', extent=[-1,12,-1,12])
        plt.draw()
        plt.suptitle('frame'%i, fontsize=12)
        savefig("flie%d.png"%i)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [plt.title](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.title)?

```
for i in range(steps):

    nor_m = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
    plt.hexbin(xxx, yyy, C, gridsize=13, cmap=matplotlib.cm.rainbow, norm=nor_m, edgecolors= 'k', extent=[-1,12,-1,12])
    plt.title('frame %d'%i, fontsize=12)
    plt.savefig("flie%d.png"%i)
```

You also had an error in the string formatting of the title call. Actually `'frame'%i` should have failed with an `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`-error.
Note also, that you don't need the `plt.draw`, since this will be called by `plt.savefig`.